# puppeteer page.evaluate cannot exposeFunction with args

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

As I saw in document ([here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction)), we can expose js function to page like this,

```js
function do_many_operations(elem) {
    let rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect;
}

async function dummy_fn1(page) {

    // Expose function here
    await page.exposeFunction("do_many_operations", do_many_operations);

    let temp = await page.evaluate(async (a, b) => {
        let elems = document.querySelectorAll("p");
        // Use function here
        let rect = await do_many_operations(elems[0]);
    }, 1, 2);
}
```

However, the code breaks with error message saying,

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: elem.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
```

That means the `elem` arg to `do_many_operations` is not a valid element or node, WHY??

Another question is, can we inject functions to browser context? So that we don't have to inject the function again and again for new pages created.

Comment: BTW, `addScriptTag` works well to solve my problem above, but still would like to know what is the recommended way to do that .

Answer (score 2):

There is a serialization process when you call a function registered with `exposeFunction`.
When you call `do_many_operations(elems[0]);`, `elems[0]` is serialized (JSON.stringify) and passed to your function in Node. On the node side, that object won't have a `getBoundingClientRect` function.
If you want to reuse code you can create functions on the browser side using `evaluate`:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.do_many_operations = function(elem) {
    let rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect;
  }
});
```

Comment: But creating the function on browser side is not what I wanted, because I have many existing functions doing the work, and I just want to reuse them in my new project, instead of copying and defining them again in code.

Comment: So you won't be able to pass elements to those functions.

Comment: So all code for parsing inside page.evaluate has to be written there, it can't be used in other methods or be extracted at all?

Comment: @MiguelStevens You could declare a function and register it in another evaluate, and then call that function. But you can't return a non-serializable object.